# Laravel Vapor- Allow unauthenticated user perform an upload

Tags: laravel, laravel-vapor

By default Laravel Vapor requires the user be authenticated to perform an upload. I need to allow an unauthenticated perform an upload. How can I do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think if you add something like this in your UserPolicy, vapor should work

```
public function before($user)
{
    if (Auth::guest()) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Be aware that this will allow unauthorized users to do **anything** the UserPolicy would typically restrict. It may have unintended side effects. It would be better to handle the second `$ability` parameter to `before` to scope it just to `uploadFiles`.

Comment: If the request is not authenticated, $request->user() will be null, so the UserPolicy will not be called.

Answer (score 0):

We handled this by overriding [the default `vapor/signed-storage-url` route's handling](https://github.com/laravel/vapor-core/blob/32b526df9a95a8e1c1e3e71a9c7c63e2594afd5a/src/Http/Controllers/SignedStorageUrlController.php#L21).

In `routes/web.php`.

```php
Route::post('vapor/signed-storage-url', [Controllers\SignedStorageUrlController::class, 'store']);
```

In our `SignedStorageUrlController`, we use the `store` function with this check removed:

```php
Gate::authorize('uploadFiles', [
    $request->user(),
    $bucket = $request->input('bucket') ?: $_ENV['AWS_BUCKET'],
]);
```

resulting in:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Support\Str;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Vapor\Http\Controllers\SignedStorageUrlController as VaporSignedStorageUrlController;

class SignedStorageUrlController extends VaporSignedStorageUrlController
{
    public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->ensureEnvironmentVariablesAreAvailable($request);

        $bucket = $request->input('bucket') ?: $_ENV['AWS_BUCKET'];

        $client = $this->storageClient();

        $uuid = (string) Str::uuid();

        $signedRequest = $client->createPresignedRequest(
            $this->createCommand($request, $client, $bucket, $key = ('tmp/'.$uuid)),
            '+5 minutes'
        );

        $uri = $signedRequest->getUri();

        return response()->json([
            'uuid' => $uuid,
            'bucket' => $bucket,
            'key' => $key,
            'url' => 'https://'.$uri->getHost().$uri->getPath().'?'.$uri->getQuery(),
            'headers' => $this->headers($request, $signedRequest),
        ], 201);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a cleaner way than overriding the route and controller would be to allow guests through the authorization gate.

According to the docs, we can allow guests to pass the gate by making the user argument optional or defaulting to null.
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/authorization#guest-users

Since the default controller method does not explicitly specify the User model, the UserPolicy will not be called for guests.  We can overcome this by defining an uploadFiles gate in the boot method of your AuthServiceProvider:

```
Gate::define('uploadFiles', function (?User $user, $bucket) {
        // Your Auth Here
    });
```